# Caching XML in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a rather large XML file that is generated - what is the best way to cache this?  It's a xml.builder file - could I use Russian Doll style caching?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely be able to take advantage of Rails 4 fragment caching as you would in any other template. [Here's an example (before cache_digests was added to Rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724069/use-cache-digests-with-xml-builder)